# for loop is not echoing the expected values from my array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am writing some code for a module for Zen Cart. $stores_id is an array containing 3 values:

```
$stores_id[0]="1";
$stores_id[1]="2";
$stores_id[2]="3";
```

With the following code I am trying to echo a hidden input field, filled with data from the array

```
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($stores_id); $i<$n; $i++)
{
  echo zen_draw_hidden_field('stores_id['. $stores_id[$i]['stores_id'] .']', htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($stores_id[$stores_id[$i]['stores_id']]), ENT_COMPAT, CHARSET, TRUE));
}
```

the echoed result is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="stores_id[1]">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="stores_id[2]">
<input type="hidden" name="stores_id[3]">
```

while I expected it to be:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="stores_id[1]">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="stores_id[2]">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="stores_id[3]">
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are nesting your 2nd parameter 1 depth too far -

```
$stores_id[$stores_id[$i]['stores_id']]
```

So when `$i == 0`, you are getting `$stores_id[1]`, which is `2`, instead of `$stores_id[0]` which is `1`. And when you get to `$i == 2` you have `$stores_id[3]` which is not in the array.

So either remove the outer array -

```
htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($stores_id[$i]['stores_id'])
```

or subtract `1` from the inner array returned value

```
htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($stores_id[$stores_id[$i]['stores_id']-1])
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I used the first option, because in normal operation the array may be filled with any combination of the values, and then the second option did not work.

Comment: Simplified the code a bit further by removing `['stores_id']`.
Now the echo line reads:
`echo zen_draw_hidden_field('stores_id['. $stores_id[$i] .']', htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($stores_id[$i]), ENT_COMPAT, CHARSET, TRUE));`